# Automapper and Base classes

Tags: .net, inheritance

First let me say that I am new to auto mapper. I have a base class with classes that inherit the base as follows:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    [Required]
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreatedOffset { get; set; }
    public Guid? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DateUpdatedOffset { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Base
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TypeCustomer CustomerType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

class to map to is as follows:

```
public class CustomerObject
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreatedOffset { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DateUpdatedOffset { get; set; }
    public TypeCustomer CustomerType { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AddressObject> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumberObject> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

code to map classes:

```
    Customer customer = GetCustomerById(customerObject.CustomerId);
    Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerObject, Customer>();
    customer = Mapper.Map<CustomerObject, Customer>(customerObject);
    customer.UpdatedBy = userId;
    customer.DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    customer.DateUpdatedOffset = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
```

when attempting to map an instance of the customer class to the customer object I am losing all of the properties from the base class.  Anyone run into this?

Comment: This code doesn't convert an instance of the customer class to the customer object. It is mapping from a CustomerObject to a Customer object. The signature for Map (and CreateMap) is Mapper.Map<TSource, TTarget>(TSource) : TTargert. Is this what you mean to do?

Answer (score 0):

first which version of AutpMapper you are using? I assume that you are using the latest version on nuget package which is 4.0.4

if yes, so this feature already exists in automapper and here is a [fiddle demonstrating that](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LJWfS6)